# Why implement Progress Indicator percentage in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, file, web, progress

I need implement a progress indicator percentage when file is loading in flutter web.

Currently the percentage is only rendered when it finishes reading and not while it is reading.

I saw many examples of how to do it but unfortunately I did not find one that allows it to be done from flutter web.

What I really want to do is display progress and then render the data to a table, but only the table and percentage are rendered when the file has been fully read.

This is a piece of code

```
Future _startFilePicker() async {
var bytes = <int>[];
FileUploadInputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement();
uploadInput.click();

uploadInput.onChange.listen((e) {
  // read file content as dataURL
  final files = uploadInput.files;
  if (files!.length == 1) {
    File file = files[0];
    FileReader reader = FileReader();

    bytes =
        Base64Decoder().convert(reader.result.toString().split(",").last);

    reader.onLoadEnd.listen((e) {
      uploadedCsv =
          Base64Decoder().convert(reader.result.toString().split(",").last);
      rowsAsListOfValues =
          const CsvToListConverter().convert(utf8.decode(uploadedCsv!));
  
      for (var value in rowsAsListOfValues) {
        list.add(UsersCsv.fromList(value));
      }
      setState(() { // here will be update de widget           
       for (int i = 1; i <= bytes.length; i++) {
            this.progress = ((i) / bytes.length);
        
      });
    });

    reader.onError.listen((fileEvent) {
      setState(() {
        option1Text = "Some Error occured while reading the file";
        print(option1Text);
        errorView = true;
      });
    });

    reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
  }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AxWC49ZMzs
Heavy processes like parsing could stop the render process, because async functions has no own thread. Try an isolate solution